# Nth child selector not working in css for background in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm having an Issue with my 3x3 Matrix, I'm trying to change the images using Nth child in CSS, but cannot get this to change. There is an example of my Nth child usage in the code below.

I'm looking to have each square in the matrix to have different images.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
HizY

```css
.box-container {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 320px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.img-box {
    width: 180px;
    height:180px;
    background-color: white;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0.15em 0.175em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid  hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.img{
  background-image:url("https://www.onlinelogomaker.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Fotolia_128673803_Subscription_Monthly_M.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 99.94%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}
.img-box:nth-child(2).img{
  background-image:url("https://www.onlinelogomaker.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Fotolia_128673803_Subscription_Monthly_M.jpg");
}
.img.active {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.headline {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
    transform: translate(210%, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.headline.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
    transform: translate(110%, 0px);
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease;
    transition: all .4s ease;
}
.headline h2 {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #333;
  font-size: 1.1em;
    width: 80%; 
}
.cell{
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Internet Services</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Safe, secure and cost-efficient broadband.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Security and Web Filter</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Security, e-safety and web-filtering services.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Infra Services</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Infrastructure solutions for your school.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Cloud Provision</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Leverage the benefits of the cloud.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Telephony Provision</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Modern, cost-effective telephony.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Finance Option</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Financial plans to suit your schools budget.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Network Services</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Wireless and switched infrastructure.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Data Services</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Information on our data services.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="img-box">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h2>Support Provision</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>Learn about our expert ongoing support.</p>
                        <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pseudo classes like nth-child match elements, not classes. So when you add it to a class, you're effectively filtering the elements its working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `nth-child` try to precise on the parent one when you apply it onto children sometimes won't work so select it by getting to `cell` as the parent like `.cell:nth-child(3) .img-box .img`

```css
.box-container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 320px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.img-box {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0.15em 0.175em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.img {
  background-image: url("https://www.onlinelogomaker.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Fotolia_128673803_Subscription_Monthly_M.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 99.94%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.row:nth-child(1) .cell:nth-child(1) .img-box .img {
  background: red;
}

.row:nth-child(1) .cell:nth-child(2) .img-box .img {
  background: green;
}

.row:nth-child(1) .cell:nth-child(3) .img-box .img {
  background: blue;
}

.row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(1) .img-box .img {
  background: cyan;
}

.row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(2) .img-box .img {
  background: skyblue;
}

.row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(3) .img-box .img {
  background: darkcyan;
}

.row:nth-child(3) .cell:nth-child(1) .img-box .img {
  background: maroon;
}

.row:nth-child(3) .cell:nth-child(2) .img-box .img {
  background: tomato;
}

.row:nth-child(3) .cell:nth-child(3) .img-box .img {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.img.active {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.headline {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
  transform: translate(210%, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.headline.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
  transform: translate(110%, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.headline h2 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 80%;
}

.cell {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Internet Services</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Safe, secure and cost-efficient broadband.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Security and Web Filter</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Security, e-safety and web-filtering services.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Infra Services</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Infrastructure solutions for your school.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Cloud Provision</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Leverage the benefits of the cloud.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Telephony Provision</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Modern, cost-effective telephony.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Finance Option</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Financial plans to suit your schools budget.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Network Services</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Wireless and switched infrastructure.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Data Services</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Information on our data services.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Support Provision</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Learn about our expert ongoing support.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Gad, thanks for the reply, I see in the snippet its applied the colour to each row, how would i now select each individual square. Thanks, HizY

Comment: now check I tried hard to understand your layout

Comment: now I think I made it clear

Comment: Thanks man, This worked a charm

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You would need to specify both the row and column classes to with `nth-child` to be able to set the child element properties.

```
.row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(2) .img-box .img {
  background: red;
}
```

```css
.box-container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 320px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.img-box {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0.15em 0.175em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.img {
  background-image: url("https://www.onlinelogomaker.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Fotolia_128673803_Subscription_Monthly_M.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 99.94%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(2) .img-box .img {
  background: red;
}

.img.active {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.headline {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(210%, 0px);
  transform: translate(210%, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.headline.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(110%, 0px);
  transform: translate(110%, 0px);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.headline h2 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 80%;
}

.cell {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Internet Services</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Safe, secure and cost-efficient broadband.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Security and Web Filter</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Security, e-safety and web-filtering services.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Infra Services</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Infrastructure solutions for your school.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Cloud Provision</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Leverage the benefits of the cloud.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Telephony Provision</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Modern, cost-effective telephony.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Finance Option</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Financial plans to suit your schools budget.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Network Services</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Wireless and switched infrastructure.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Data Services</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Information on our data services.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="img-box">
          <div class="img"></div>
          <div class="headline">
            <h2>Support Provision</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <p>Learn about our expert ongoing support.</p>
            <a href="">Read more <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this worked first try haha!